# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows: Can't handle signal

Tags: c, windows, bash, signals, bash-on-windows

I developped, last year, a program in C on my old computer (*on Ubuntu*) in which I used 3 signals: SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 and SIGQUIT.
But now, I'm on a new computer (*on Windows*) and I installed "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows". But in this terminal, when I execute my project's binary, an error occured: "Can't handle SIGUSR1Can't handle SIGUSR2Can't handle SIGQUIT".
[image: Can't handle signal]
I understand the problem, but I really dont know how to solve it.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to include the smallest sample of code that demonstrates this problem. Good luck.

Comment: I just use "kill()" and "sigaction()" functions. The problem doesn't come from the program, it come from the terminal "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were subtle differences in the way signals are handled on the WSL, compared to "real" Linux. However, I just tried a simple program that uses `signal()` to trap USR1, and it seemed to work as I expected. So I guess we would need to know more about where the failure arises in your program. For example, is the message "Can't handle SIGUSR1" coming from your code, or from the "system" somewhere?

Comment: I know my code works, I tested it on a Linux Boot and have been marked on the project. So, I think, it's the "system" or the terminal. But how solve this problem?